# Haskell - too few arguments

Tags: haskell

I want to write a Haskell program that calculates the sum of numbers between 2 given numbers.
I have the following code:

```
sumInt :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumInt x y
   | x > y = 0
   | otherwise = x + sumInt x+1 y
```

But when I compile it I get the following error:

> SumInt is applied to too few arguments.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?
+1 even just to negate, this question is definitely within the scope of SO (and it's a good one too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parentheses around `x+1`:

```
| otherwise = x + sumInt (x + 1) y
```

The reason is that function application binds more tightly than operators, so whenever you see

```
f x <> y
```

This is always parsed as

```
(f x) <> y
```

and never as

```
f (x <> y)
```

Comment: How did the compiler try to read it when it reported the error? can you demonstrate using parentheses?

Comment: @MasterMastic The compiler would have read this particular expression as `x + (sumInt x) + (1 y)`.  Due to polymorphism of numeric literals, `1 y` actually typechecks, it just doesn't have an instance of `Num` available that is a function.  The error came from `sumInt x`, which is said to have type `Int`, with `x` being known as `Int`, so the first error it encounters is a mismatch between `Int -> Int` and `Int`, for which it suggests you don't have enough parameters.