# Haskell parentheses for function application binding

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, operator-precedence

I'm learning Haskell. I defined the following function (I know I don't need `addToList` and I can also do Point-free notation I'm just in the process of playing with language concepts):

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []    = []
map f (x:xs)  = addToList (f x) map f xs
  where
    addToList :: a -> [a] -> [a]
    addToList x [] = [x]
    addToList x xs = x:xs
```

This produces a compile error:

```
with actual type `(a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]'                                                                                                                   
Relevant bindings include                                                                                                                                                   
  f :: a -> b (bound at PlayGround.hs:12:5)                                                                                                                                 
  map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] (bound at PlayGround.hs:11:1)                                                                                                               
Probable cause: `map' is applied to too few arguments                                                                                                                       
In the second argument of `addToList', namely `map'                                                                                                                         
In the expression: addToList (f x) map f xs
```

If I put parantheses around map it works:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []    = []
map f (x:xs)  = addToList (f x) (map f xs)
  where
    addToList :: a -> [a] -> [a]
    addToList x [] = [x]
    addToList x xs = x:xs
```

I understand that function application binds more tightly than operators (as discussed in [Haskell - too few arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155472/haskell-too-few-arguments)), however, I don't understand how the compiler would parse the above differently without the parantheses.

Comment: Style note: `x:[]` is equivalent to `[x]`. Hence, the line `addToList x xs = [x]` is redundant: the next line will return `[x]` anyway. This further implies that `addToList` and `(:)` are exactly the same thing. Indeed, one can directly use `map f (x:xs) = (:) (f x) (map f xs)` or equivalently `map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs` using infix notation.

Comment: @chi This is why I wrote "I know I don't need addToList[...]"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parsing is a distinct step that is completed *before* type checking occurs. The expression

```
addToList (f x) map f xs
```

has as much meaning to the parser as `s1 (s2 s3) s4 s2 s5` has to you. It doesn't know anything about what the names *mean*. It takes the lexical structure of the string and turns it into a parse tree like

```
                        *5
                      /   \
                     /    xs
                    *4
                  /   \
                 /     f
                *3
              /   \
             /     map
            *2
          /   \
  addToList    *1
              / \
             f   x
```

Once the parse tree is complete, then each node is tagged with its type, and type checking can occur. Since function application is denoted simply by juxtaposition, the type checker knows that the left child of a node is a function, the right child is the argument, and the root is the result.

The type checker can proceed roughly as follows, doing an pre-order traversal of the tree. (I'll alter the type signatures slightly to distinguish unrelated type variables until they are unified.)

1. `addToList :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, so it takes an argument of type `a` and returns a function of type `[a] -> [a]`. The value of `a` is not yet known.
2. `f :: b -> c`, so it takes an argument of type `b` and returns a value of type `c`. The values of `b` and `c` are not yet known.
3. `x` has type `d`. The value of `d` is not yet known.
4. Letting `b ~ d`, `f` can be applied to `x`, so `*1 :: c`
5. Letting `a ~ c`, `addToList` is applied to `*1`, so `*2 :: [a] -> [a]`
6. Uh oh. `*2` expects an argument of type `[a]`, but it is being applied to `map :: (e -> f) -> [e] -> [f]`. The type checker does not know how to unify a list type and a function type, which produces the error you see.

Comment: Thanks for the great response!

Answer (score 10):

The simple way to see that something is wrong is to note that the expression:

```
addToList (f x) map f xs
```

is applying 4 arguments to `addToList` whereas:

```
addToList (f x) (map f xs)
```

is applying two arguments to `addToList` (which is what `addToList` "expects").

**Update**

Note that even though `map` takes two arguments, this expression:

```
addToList a map c d
```

is parsed as:

```
(((addToList a) map) c) d
```

So here's a possible explanation of what GHC is thinking...

1. `addToList (f x)` has type `[a] -> [a]` - i.e. it is a function which takes a list.
2. `map` has type `(c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]`. It is not a list, but with additional arguments it could produce a list.
3. So when GHC sees `addTolist (f x) map` and can't type check it, it sees that if `map` only had a few more arguments, like this:

   ```
   addToList (f x) (map ...)
   ```

at least the second argument to `addToList` would be a list - so perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: So, why is the compile error stating "Probable cause: `map' is applied to too few arguments"?

Comment: GHC is trying really hard to make sense of what you've written. It is possible that `addToList a b c d` could be valid, but not in the "everyday" use of it - and that's why I say `addToList` "expects" only two arguments. This idea of just counting "expected" arguments should serve you well in tracking down problems like this.

Comment: But wouldn't the compiler parse the tree all the way down to arrive at "map f xs", replace it with a list and traverse back up on the parse tree? Why would it stop at the highest level of "addToList ..." without parsing that expression further?

Comment: Note that `addToList a b map d` is the same as `(((addToList a) b) map) d`, so in a sense `map` is not being applied to any arguments, so perhaps this is what GHC is referring to.